# Переход из браузера в приложение

Tags: javascript, html

Часто наблюдаю такую картину: при переходе по ссылку, скажем, для вступления в группу в telegram, браузер предлагает продолжить в приложении.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как это работает?

Comment: браузер просто переходит по ссылке с кастомной схемой, в данном случае `tg://` в то же время, данная схема должна быть зарегистрирована в системе и ей должно быть сопоставлено приложение, которое будет открываться

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61136606/12915495

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такие ссылки работают аналогично tel: и mailto:
Например, для того чтобы открыть viber-bot по ссылке из браузера - можно использовать `<a href="viber://pa?chatURI=bot_name">Написать боту</a>`